# System::String para basic_string

Tags: c++-cli

Estava procurando como converter System::String para string "normal", e achei um comando:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
System::String^ mstr = "PTSO";
std::string mstrr msclr::interop::marshal_as< string >(mstr);
```

Funcionou, mas tentei fazer uma função para "facilitar" o uso, e não consegui. Tentei assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
string SysStrToStr(System::String^ sstr) {
        return msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(sstr);
    }
```

Deu esse erro:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __clrcall SysStrToStr(class System::String ^)" (?SysStrToStr@@YM?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@P$AAVString@System@@@Z) already defined in MyForm.obj
```

**Esclarecendo:**
Estou criando uma aplicação CLR(Formulários) no Visual Studio 2012(C++), e quando preciso passar o conteúdo de um RichTextBox(text) para uma função, ele manda System::string, e sempre preciso converter para string "normal"(std::string) para usar.

Comment: O que você chama de *string* normal? Seria `System::String^`? Isso é a *string* mais anormal que eu conheço :) Se eu fosse você não tentaria usar C++/CLI do .Net. Isso não é nem C++, nem .Net :) É um mostrengo que nem a MS usa (até usa para interoperabilidade mas só, não para fazer algo útil).

Comment: Vou ser mais claro na pergunta. Um momento.

Comment: Eu não vou saber responder, mas larga disso, usa uma tecnologia decente :)

Comment: Como assim? '-'

Comment: leia o que eu escrevi acima, isso é uma aberração da natureza. OU faça as coisas em C++ puro ou use C#.

Comment: Aparentemente você definiu a função em um cabeçalho (arquivo .h) e o incluiu mais de uma vez no projeto, resultando em definição dupla. Marcar a função como `inline` resolve?